# I have two branches in my git. The one is in green (master) other (personal-website/master) is in red in color

Tags: linux, git, github, terminal, git-branch

why the second branch is showing in red color. And also when I entered `git branch` there is only one branch: master. When I tried to delete second branch (personal-website/master), it showing error (branch 'personal-website/master' not found). What could be the issue. How to remove it? [image attached below]

[git terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr6Dx.png)

Comment: personal-website/master branch is on remote ?

Comment: You have a remote named `personal-website`.  Your local repo's HEAD is at the same point as the branch master on that remote.  What does `git-branch -a` show?  Do you want to delete the branch on the remote, or just delete the remote completely?

Comment: what command are you using to delete ?

Comment: @WilliamPursell to delete the remote completely. 
when I type `git branch -a`. it shows two branches `* master` & `remotes/personal-website/master`

Comment: @IMParasharG git branch -d command.

Comment: It sounds like you want `git remote remove personal-website`.  This will not change anything on the remote, but will disassociate it from the local repo (unless you have multiple remotes setup targeting the same repo, but it doesn't sound like you do.) The operation is reversible (you can easily add the remote again if you want).

Answer (score 0):

The `personal-website/master` is a remote branch that presents an upstream to your local branch `master`. In order to remove your remote branch, you need to perform a **delete** push as illustrated below:

```sh
git push personal-website master --delete
```

Comment: showing an error:  ! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)

Comment: You should not attempt to delete this branch name from the other repository: it is the *only* branch name in that repository right now.

Comment: Well sounds you don't have write permission or the remote is protected.

Answer (score 0):

The red color here does not indicate any kind of error.  Instead, it distinguishes a *remote-tracking name* from a *branch* name.  By default, when Git applies color to branch names, it puts local branch names in green and remote-tracking names in red.

A remote-tracking name is a name that your Git software maintains in your Git repository based on a branch name that your Git software observed in *some other Git repository*.  Git is a *distributed* version control system—a "DVCS", with the D standing for distributed—which in this case means that repositories get replicated.  The replicas can be exact duplicates, or approximate duplicates.  As you add new commits to *your* repository, your duplicate of their repository becomes less-exact, because the new commits you have added to your repository are, at this point, *only* in *your* repository.

Your branch names, in your repository, exist to help you keep track of your commits.  Git itself doesn't actually need *any* branch names: Git finds commits by their hash IDs, which are very large numbers, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Every commit gets a *unique* hash ID, and two separate repositories have the *same* commit if and only if they have a commit that has the *same hash ID*.  So two repositories, meeting up with `git push` or `git fetch`, can tell which commits they both share, and which commits one repository has that the other repository lacks, just by comparing hash IDs.<sup>1</sup>  It's the commits, and their numbers, that actually matter to Git.  But the numbers *look* random and are not usable by mere humans, so we use names: *branch* names in particular.

But your branch names, in your repository, are *your* names.  You get to do whatever you want with them.  They're not anyone else's branch names.  Those other repositories you have your repository call up, and give commits to or get commits from or both, have *their own* branch names that remember commit hash IDs for *them*.

When your Git software calls up their Git software, your Git code gets to see what their names are and what hash IDs are stored in them.  Your Git will take those names and *change* them into *remote-tracking names*, and stuff those remote-tracking names into your repository.  By changing the names, your Git ensures that *their* branch names don't collide with yours.  But now it may be important to you to be able to see, at a glance, which names are whose.  The color distinction is there to help out with that.

As long as you ever intend to connect to their repository *again*, you should not worry about your own Git carrying around their branch names (translated into your remote-tracking names).  If the red color bothers you, you can instruct your Git software to use some other color, you can configure some settings:

- `color.branch.remote` controls the remote-tracking-name color from `git branch -r` or `git branch -a`.
- `color.decorate.remoteBranch` controls the remote-tracking-name color from `git log`.

(Why one is `remote` and one is `remoteBranch` is a mystery and a historical oddity.  However, Git documentation often uses the phrase *remote-tracking branch name* instead of the simpler *remote-tracking name*.)

Removing the remote entirely, as in [William Pursell's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289056/i-have-two-branches-in-my-git-the-one-is-in-green-master-other-personal-webs#comment127718706_72289056), will remove the remote-tracking name as well.  However, this means you can no longer run `git fetch personal-website` or `git push personal-website` to conveniently obtain new commits *from* the other Git repository, or send your commits *to* the remote repository.  (You can still get and send commits, you just cannot do it *conveniently* by using the short word `personal-website`.  That short word `personal-website` is what Git calls a *remote*.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This unique hash ID trick is the real magic of Git: how it manages to make sure that no two repositories ever accidentally use the *same* number for a *different* commit, and yet always use the same number for the *same* commit, is a mathematical marvel.  It's also fundamentally flawed: someday, Git will fail.  The sheer *size* of the number space puts that day off for a long time: billions or trillions of years, we hope, so that we'll all be long dead and won't care.